# How can the records in CoreData be viewed? | Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am storing data in core data, would like to view the records without calling them in something like a ListView, anyway to just view the records somehow in Xcode 14 in table format like SQL?

Comment: Not that I know of but you can use an 3rd party app or the SQLite client from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can view the record using through dictionary directory path

let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

let docsDir = dirPaths[0]

print(docsDir)

Comment: Thanks, can you look at my latest question? I appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74033542/issue-deleting-records-from-one-to-many-relationship-core-data-swift